# jqGrid datecolumn not sorting

Tags: jqgrid

Been looking around for answer in stackoverflow but so far nothing has worked. Currently the order is totally random. But i need it to be able to sort. Incoming date is in format 2017-01-13 12:30:34.314. No matter what i cant get it sorted.

Using jqgrid 4.5.2

```js
{name:'tahtaeg', width: 25, classes: 'textAlignAsBox', title: false, resizable: true,
    date: true, editable: vvj||strj,
    editoptions:{
        dataInit: function(element){
            jQuery(element).datepicker({
                dateFormat: sos.kvp.i18n.dateFormat.dateTimePicker,
                mindate: 0,
                showHour: false,
                showMinute: false,
                showTime: false,
                alwaysSetTime: false,
                showButtonPanel: false,
                onSelect:function(){
                    jQuery(this).datepicker("hide");
                    jqGridTegevused.jqGrid('saveCell',row,col);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    sorttype:'date',
    formatter: 'date',
    formatoptions: {newformat:'d.m.Y'},
    editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: globalKvp.util.jqGridValidateDate}
},

 datatype: 'json',
            cellEdit: true,
            sortable:true,
            loadonec: true,
            cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
            restoreAfterSelect: false,
            saveAfterSelect: true,
            editurl: 'clientArray',
            autowidth: true,
            sortname: 'tahtaeg',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            scrollOffset: 0,
            height: '100%',
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: false,
            hidegrid: false,
            caption: "",
            loadui: "disable",
            altRows:true,
            altclass: 'ui-jqgrid-alternate',
```

Comment: Which `datatype` you use? If you load the data from the server (`url` parameter of jqGrid), then it's important to know whether you use `loadonce: true` option. Please, include **always** in all your questions about jqGrid the information **which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from, which fork of jqGrid** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: @Oleg I added more information, hope this helps. I added in loadonce, and now it sorts. But when the table loading is completed first time, it is still unsorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code use `loadonec: true` instead of `loadonce: true`. It seems be a typing error. As the result jqGrid supposes **server side** sorting, paging and filtering/searching. If the user clicks on the column header of some column then the grid will be reloaded from the server in the sort order, which returns the server.

By the way you use `sortname: 'tahtaeg'` and `sortorder: 'desc'`. It means that the server have to return **correctly sorted** initial data from the server.

I don't recommend you to use retro version 4.5.2 (it's almost 4 years old), which is dead and not supported already since some years. I recommend you upgrade to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.6, which you can download from GitHub or to load all the files directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

After upgrading to free jqGrid you will have better performance and you can use many new features, for example, the new option `forceClientSorting: true`, which will make *client side sorting and filtering* initially loaded data. I'd recommend you additionally to use Font Awesome 4.7 icons instead of old jQuery UI icons. You will need just include Font Awesome CSS and to add `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data) for the code example.

Comment: Well... to upgrade it i need to speak with client and supervisors. Dont know if they allow it.

Comment: @MarkoTaht: It's your internal problem. What is about fixing `loadonec: true` to `loadonce: true`? Is your original problem fixed now?

Comment: Yes. It is sorting now. + i can do the initial sorting on the serverside, so when loading up the table it gets ordered data.